# getMethods Reflection API result is ambiguous with Interface

Tags: java, reflection, interface

Please have a look on the scenario and suggest how can I remove the following issue.

1. We have an interface **BaseRepository** which is already build in having a method commitData(), retrieveData(), sortByLength().

   ```
    public interface BaseRepository{
          public void commitData();
          public Object retrieveData();
          public Object sortByLength();
       }
   ```
2. Interface **FileRepository** which extends **BaseRepository** having methods commitData(), fileNames() i.e.

   ```
   public interface FileRepository extends BaseRepository{
               public void commitData();
               public List fileNames();
           }
   ```
3. Interface **ObjectRepository** which extends both **BaseRepository** and **FileRepository** with no methods in it.
4. Using Java Reflection API I try to get the methods define in the Interfaces for further processing, but getting method commitData 2 times i.e. following piece of code will give me 2 time commitData in the console

   ```
   for(Method method : ObjectRepository.class.getMethods()){
               System.out.println(method.getName());
           }
   ```

output is:

> commitData  retrieveData  sortByLength  commitData  fileNames

I am using Java 1.6.

Comment: BaseRepository and FileRepository  has method called commitData().

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Method::getDeclaringClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) to distinguish between them.

```
for(Method method : ObjectRepository.class.getMethods()){
        System.out.println(method.getDeclaringClass() + " " + method.getName());
}
```

See http://ideone.com/y3Djvf